# Fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly while pushing to Git repository

Tags: git, push

I created a new repository called DirectorySocket, and from my project directory called DirectorySocket I did the following:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:neilghosh/DirectorySocket.git
$ git commit -m "Initial version"
$ git push origin master
```

And I got the following error:

> ERROR: Permission to neilghosh/DirectorySocket.git denied to
>   neilghosh/googly. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Why is it trying to push to another repository of mine on GitHub?
This happens also after I deleted the `.git` folder and started over.

Comment: Another case in the event Google brings you here. I was trying https connection with github and it was failing every time between 50 and 95% complete upload. I took the moment to `ssh-keygen` and followed @manojlds link (there's another link for ssh keys at the bottom) and it worked. Slowly, but it worked.

Comment: Another answer for Googlers: trying to pull from a path with an unescaped space in it (e.g. "/Users/rog/James James/project") will cause this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since it is your repository, check if the keys and token are setup properly as per the instructions provided by GitHub.

http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

As a first step, see if

```
 ssh -T git@github.com
```

works.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of leads [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Git_push_fails_with_.22fatal:_The_remote_end_hung_up_unexpectedly.22.3F) - it is most likely an authorization issue. Have you uploaded your public key to GitHub?

What is your network situation? I get this response behind my restrictive corporate firewall - the answer there is to use [the smart HTTP support](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support) now supported by GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, The problem was with authentication  "ssh -T git@github.com" was not even working. However the message was misleading that it was trying to push the code to a different repository of mine. Solved the problem by adding another public key in the github. [link](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/)

Answer (score 1):

Direct link to GitHub explanation here:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys