# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly with a fetch upstream

Tags: git, github

I am following the instructions on github for forking a repo but everything up to not including configure the remotes works. I am told to run the following code but git fetch upstream returns the following `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`
Whats causing this, and could someone explain what it means to configure the remotes.

```
$ cd Spoon-KnifeChanges the active directory in the prompt to the newly cloned "Spoon-Knife" directory
$ git remote add upstream git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.gitAssigns the original repo to a remote called "upstream"
$ git fetch upstream
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just start fresh:

```
$ rm -rf Spoon-Knife
$ git clone git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
$ cd Spoon-Knife
$ git remote add upstream git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
$ git fetch upstream
```

As for the `remote end hung up unexpectedly` error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6808653/1101070) Stack Overflow question (among many) -- most likely reason is that your SSH keys weren't set up correctly.

Comment: I am not getting a fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly error for cloning. huh?

Comment: well I have run ssh -T git@github.com and it authenticates fine.

Comment: I followed them all and as soon as I run git clone I get a fatal: The Remote end hung up.

Comment: I am running mac osx and I am running them exactly no sudo or nothing.

Comment: omg so sorry, I was typing the wrong username i.e. anders instead of anderskitson