# Git Checkout error

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

While trying to checkout the repository, i'm getting the below error

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test'..
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Any idea on how to debug this error, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set up SSH keys correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808653/fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-pushing-to-git-repository possible copy

Comment: I'm not following the steps provided in the duplicate link: All i'm doing is to 'checkout' a repository, not a commit or create a repository.

Comment: Okay, I had to change the  SSH key, which was not authenticating me. The issue is resolved now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Look at

```
yourdir/.git/config
```

And make sure it's looking at the correct place. If it is, make sure that you have permission. It may be a key issue.

EDIT: Never mind, your not going to have a .git directory if you can't clone. But the issue is still either pathing or permission.