# Change default email in Git gives error on pull

Tags: git, pull

I am aware [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808653/fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-pushing-to-git-repository) because I am getting the same error message. Yesterday I added a new email address to my github account and set it to default. Today I tried a `git pull` and received this error:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I attempted `ssh -T git@github.com` and it succeeded. Is it now true that I need to reset or get new git keys? If not, what could the problem be?

EDIT: Github was having problems today. The problem has been solved now that github is back up.

Comment: I've been having problems with github today. I wanted to clone a repo and I got "The remote end hung up unexpectedly". But now I did it again and it worked. I think github is having a bad day

Comment: As @iberbeu pointed out and as you can see in [Github's status message log](https://status.github.com/messages), there were some issues on Github today. Since status is now back to green, please try again and commet or edit your questions with your new results

Comment: Thank you both, the error was on github's side.